# Express.js sometimes passes the router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing simple CRUD app with Node.js & Express.js, And it works well with Local environment.

But the problem is from real server.

[image]

When I click register button, user register process with PowerShell works well directly, and in MongoDB Query process works well. But in front-side it works really slowly (about 20~30 seconds). But When I checked the MongoDB DB it's already registered, but the page did not get the new data Even If I clicked F5 button many times.

[image]

When I check the console.log when I clicked the F5 button I found that it doesn't passed the admin router so that it cannot get the new data. It only requests js and css files and I don't know why.

```
GET /javascripts/admin.js 304 0.494 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/admin.css 304 0.613 ms - -
```

But after 20-30 seconds later the admin router works again and also in front view data are changed.

Here's my code.

```
/* Admin User Management Page Router*/
router.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    User.find({}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      res.render('admin', {
        dataArray: result
      })
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})

/* User Delete Router */
router.get(`/delete/:name`, (req, res) => {
  let name = req.params.name;

  User.deleteOne({
    'name': name
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  })

  let cmd = `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8\n
  Remove-LocalUser -Name "${name}"\n`

  exec(cmd, {
    'shell': 'powershell.exe'
  }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // do whatever with stdout
    console.log(stderr)
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(stdout)
  })
})
```

And here's the user register router

```
/* Register Process Router */
router.get('/register/:name', (req, res) => {
  let name = req.params.name;
  console.log(name);
  /* Find password with password information */
  User.find({
    'name': name
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      console.log(result);
      let password = Base64.decode(result[0].password)

      /* MongoDB Update Query */
      User.findOneAndUpdate({
        'name': name,
      }, {
        $set: {
          registerStatus: '등록완료'
        }
      }, {
        returnNewDocument: true
      }, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
      })

      let cmd = `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8\n
      Write-Output 'UTF-8 with BOM Encoding으로 작업완료'\n
      $Password = ('${password}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force)\n
      Write-Output '패스워드 데이터 암호화 및 SecureString 변수로 저장완료'\n
      New-LocalUser "${name}" -Password $Password -FullName "${name}" -Description "${name}" -PasswordNeverExpires\n
      Write-Output 'Local User 그룹에 사용자 정보 등록 완료'\n
      Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "${result[0].company}" -Member "${name}"\n
      Write-Output 'Local 회사 그룹에 등록 완료'\n
      Write-Output '-------------------------------------------'\n
      Write-Output '작업이 완료되었습니다'\n`

      exec(cmd, {
        'shell': 'powershell.exe'
      }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        // do whatever with stdout
        console.log(stderr)
        res.redirect('/admin')
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(stdout)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

What I really don't understand is that data changes very quickly in a local environment.

And If you want to show all of my router code, You can use with this [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/writingdeveloper/77ff896f5a08311c2274469d0a639add)

Answer (score 0):

It's because u are not waiting for the Mongo query to complete.

You are now awaiting or putting the logging mechanism inside the return callback of mongo. Thus, effectively you are running the mongo query + loggin with powershell and redirecting at the same time. So, if by chance mongo query is updated before the redirect it's well and good otherwise it will redirect to admin before the mongo part finishes.

Either put the entire login mechanism inside the mongo callback or use promises.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
    'name': name,
}, {
    $set: {
        registerStatus: '등록완료'
    }
}, {
    returnNewDocument: true
}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(doc);

    let cmd = `...`

    exec(cmd, {
        ...
    }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        ....
    });
});
```

Though I would recommend 100% to use promises instead of using callbacks. and if you are using mongoose then it already supports promises OOTB.

To answer the question:

> What I really don't understand is that data changes very quickly in a local environment.

This is because you are accessing local mongo which will be faster, but when you are using a remote mongo DB is most often the slowest cog in the overall application.